# How do I use PipelineParam so that I can feed in different argument values to my components through the Kubeflow UI?

Tags: kubeflow

I currently am loading components from YAML files and have a separate config file where the arguments are mapped to values. For example, if there’s a component named train_model then there’s a config dictionary that looks like `{"learning_rate": 0.001, "batch_size": 64}`.

I’d normally do this in when compiling the pipeline:

```
spec_train = kfp.components.load_component_from_file("./train_model.yaml")
op_train = spec_train(**config)
```

Doing this in this fashion means that I’m going to have to re-compile the pipeline every time I want to run my pipeline with different parameter values. What I found that I could do is use run parameters, but when I set the run parameters via the UI and create a run the values aren’t being passed properly.

As of now it looks something like this:

```
@dsl.pipeline(name=RUN_NAME)
def pipeline_func(
    learning_rate
):
    spec_train = kfp.components.load_component_from_file("./train_model.yaml")
    config["learning_rate"] = learning_rate
    op_train = spec_train(**config)
```

How should I be using run parameters to change them at run time?